# How to return a Map<String, List<CustomVO>> from single Room entity with Android Room

Tags: android, android-room

Im investigating Android Rooms support for returning Maps from query's

I cannot get past this build error

```
error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [columnOne,columnTwo,columnThree,columnFour,columnFive,columnSix,columnSeven,columnEight] in org.my.MyDataVO even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [columnA,columnB]
    public abstract java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<org.my.MyDataVO>> fetchMap(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

My DAO Query resembles:-

```
@MapInfo(keyColumn = "column_a", valueColumn = "column_b")
@Query("SELECT column_a, column_b FROM my_data_table WHERE my_key_column = :myKeyColumn")
fun fetchMap(myKeyColumn: String): Map<String, List<org.my.MyDataVO>>
```

My DO object resembles:-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "my_data_table",
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["key_column"], unique = false),
    ]
)
@TypeConverters(MyDataVOListTypeConverter::class)
data class BookTableContentChildrenDO(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "key_column") val keyColumn: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_a") val columnA: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_b") val columnB: List<org.my.MyDataVO>
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "my_data_table_local_id")
    var myDataTableLocalId: Long = 0L
}
```

My Value Object MyDataVO resembles:-

```
@Serializable
data class MyDataVO(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_one") val columnOne: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_two") val columnTwo: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_three") val columnThree: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_four") val columnFour: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_five") val columnFive: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_six") val columnSix: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_seven") val columnSeven: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_eight") val columnEight: Long,
)
```

Is what I am attempting not possible?

Where have I made my mistake?

Why cannot room map `my_data_table.column_b` to a `List<org.my.MyDataVO>`

**UPDATE**

I managed to resolve the build error by adding all my TypeConverters to the `@Database` abstract class definition

However I am now facing a runtime error which seems very strange

I have type converters for both a single instance of `org.my.MyDataVO` and a `List<org.my.MyDataVO>`, Room is employing the Single instance TypeConverter to decode the `List<org.my.MyDataVO>`

as when I attempt to call my DAO `fetchMap()` function it fails with

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the object '{', but had 'EOF' instead
    JSON input: .....xxx","columnSix":1,"columnSeven":1,"columnEight":""}]}]
```

Why is Room using the wrong TypeConverter?

If I do not mention the Single instance TypeConverter in my `@Database` abstract class I get the build error.

**UPDATE 2**

I can get this to work if I change the DAO `fetchMap` method return type to `Map<String, List<Any>>`

Now Room employs the correct type converter and I can fetch the map ok

**UPDATE 3**
Following further testing I have discovered although I do not experience any crashes or build issues my DAO is not working as I require. Although I am inserting multiple entry lists of `org.my.MyDataVO`, the lists returned by my fetchMap function only ever contain one entry. Why cant Room return the complete list as stored in the DB table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why cant Room return the complete list as stored in the DB table?

In short you cannot have a column as a List/Array directly.

so `@ColumnInfo(name = "column_b") val columnB: List<org.my.MyDataVO>` is not going to work.

Add a POJO such as

```
data class MyDataVOListHolder(
    val myDataVOListHolder: List<org.my.MyDataVO>
)
```

and then use the POJO for the column type e.g.

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "column_b") val columnB: MyDataVOListHolder
```

Obviously you will need suitable Typeconverters to convert a myDataVOListHolder to and from a type that Room can handle (e.g. JSON String).

As an example :-

```
lateinit var db: TheDatabase
lateinit var dao: BookTableContentChildrenDODao
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getDao()

    dao.insert(
        BookTableContentChildrenDO(keyColumn = "AAA", columnA = "Blah", columnB =  MyDataVOListHolder(myDataVOListHolder = createMyDataVOList()))
    )
    dao.insert(
        BookTableContentChildrenDO(keyColumn = "BBB", columnA = "Blah", columnB =  MyDataVOListHolder(myDataVOListHolder = createMyDataVOList()))
    )
    dao.insert(
        BookTableContentChildrenDO(keyColumn = "CCC", columnA = "Blah", columnB =  MyDataVOListHolder(myDataVOListHolder = createMyDataVOList()))
    )

    for(m in dao.fetchMap("BBB")) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","Key is ${m.key}")
        for (myDataVo: MyDataVO in m.value.myDataVOListHolder) {
            Log.d("DBINFO-EXTRA","\t C1 = ${myDataVo.columnOne} C2 = ${myDataVo.columnTwo} C3 = ${myDataVo.columnThree} etc...."
            )
        }
    }
}

fun createMyDataVOList(): List<MyDataVO> {
    var myDataVoList = ArrayList<MyDataVO>()
    for (i in 1 until 5) {
        myDataVoList.add(
            MyDataVO((i * 3).toLong(),"col2_" +i.toString(),i % 2 == 0,"col4","col5","col6","col7",i.toLong())
        )
    }
    return myDataVoList
}
```

results in the log containing :-

```
D/DBINFO: Key is Blah
D/DBINFO-EXTRA:      C1 = 3 C2 = col2_1 C3 = false etc....
D/DBINFO-EXTRA:      C1 = 6 C2 = col2_2 C3 = true etc....
D/DBINFO-EXTRA:      C1 = 9 C2 = col2_3 C3 = false etc....
D/DBINFO-EXTRA:      C1 = 12 C2 = col2_4 C3 = true etc....
```

Comment: I have those type converters already

Comment: @Hector that's amazing that you knew what I was going to name the class to be converted as MyDataVOListHolder. P.S. added a working example based upon the code  in my answer (accept used MyDataVO directly rather from elsewhere)